# geo in Intent is not working in the Android app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-virtual-device, geo

I am simply trying to load the Maps application in my app but it always get closed with a message, `Unfortunately, the app has stopped.`

I have searched other stackoverflow answers as well, but not getting it that why this is getting forced close every time I clicked the `Show Map` button.

My code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.himanshu.intents.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:onClick="onClickSM"
    android:text="Show Map" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
 public void onClickSM(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent (android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("geo:<28.629404>,<77.086824>?q=<28.629404>,<77.086824>"));
    startActivity(i);
 }
}
```

LogCat Messsages:

`08-09 14:31:58.142: D/dalvikvm(2001): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
08-09 14:31:58.372: D/(2001): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7f424f0, tid 2001
08-09 14:31:58.422: W/EGL_emulation(2001): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-09 14:31:58.432: D/OpenGLRenderer(2001): Enabling debug mode 0
08-09 14:32:02.632: D/AndroidRuntime(2001): Shutting down VM
08-09 14:32:02.632: W/dalvikvm(2001): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2d72b20)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001): Process: com.himanshu.intents, PID: 2001
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     ... 11 more
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:<28.629404>,<77.086824>?q=<28.629404>,<77.086824> }
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at com.himanshu.intents.MainActivity.onClickSM(MainActivity.java:32)
08-09 14:32:02.632: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     ... 14 more`

Answer (score 2):

First, the `geo:` URL you are trying to parse is not one of [the documented and supported structures](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps), above and beyond the invalid `<` and `>` noted in cygery's answer.

Second, your device or emulator may not have a map application on it that honors `geo:` `Intent`s.

Comment: I even tried, `i.setData(Uri.parse("geo:47.6,-122.3"));` but the same problem persists. I read somewhere that the AVD must support the Google API. I installed the same for the API 19 (I am using). Then how to rectify this problem?

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal: Just because you installed something does not mean that your AVD is using it. Make sure your AVD has "Google APIs" in the "Target Name" column in the AVD Manager.

Comment: I implemented the same as you said, but my Maps app is only showing a black screen with a search at the top. What should I do now?

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal: Try running the Maps app directly from the home screen launcher. If you get the same result, then the problem is with the emulator, Google Maps, or your network (e.g., a firewall), and not your app.

Comment: I tried that too earlier. Same thing persists. Don't know what to do to rectify this problem now. :(

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal: The problem is not with your app. I rarely use an emulator for working with Google Maps, so I do not have any particular advice on trying to get that to work better for you.

Comment: It's working perfectly in my device. But, if anyone knows how to rectify this problem, do comment on it further.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<` and `>` in the URI:

```
i.setData(Uri.parse("geo:28.629404,77.086824?q=28.629404,77.086824"));
```